# Protractor Async/Await Error: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, jasmine, protractor

I'm refactoring my framework with protractor Async/Await to avoid sloppy browser.sleep() all over the code base.

Following are the steps of test followed by code as an example:

```
Opens ChromeBrowser
Logins with the credentials
Selects a customer
Clicks on "Manage Customer" button.
```

**Could you please help me with below Error:**

```
Report destination:   target\e2e\screenshots\my-report.html
[12:42:21] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:42:21] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

(node:18208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because you
r test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
    at runWaitForAngularScript.then (C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at customer.cusSelection (C:\Users\Ashish\Documents\Protractor\scripts\CustomerSelection.js:7:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:18208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18208) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[12:42:25] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:42:25] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Below are the Conf.js, Scenario_01.js & corresponding modules for your kind reference:

**Conf.js:**

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/e2e/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html',
  ignoreSkippedSpecs: true,
  reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true  ,
  showSummary: true,
  showQuickLinks: true,
  showConfiguration: true,
  reportTitle: "Protractor Automation Report",
  reportFailedUrl: true,
  inlineImages: true,
});

exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

suites: {
    Scenario1: './Scenario_01.js', 
},

SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

capabilities: {
    'shardTestFiles': false,
    'maxInstances': 1,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
     'args': ['disable-extensions', 'start-maximized']  //'--headless',
    }
},
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
getPageTimout: 10000,
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true, // is True, prints colors to terminal
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000, 
    print: function () {}
},
beforeLaunch: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
    reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
},

onPrepare: function () {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter( new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({savePath: 'target/screenshots'}));
}
};
```

**Scenario_01.js:**

```
describe('Scenario_01', function() {

 var common = require('./scripts/CloseBrowsers.js');    
 var Login = require('./scripts/Login.js'); 
 var customer = require('./scripts/CustomerSelection.js');

 it('Login', function() {
         browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); 
         Login.login('admin','Adminpwd');
     });

     it('CustomerSelection', function() {
         browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
         customer.cusSelection();
     });

afterAll(function(){
    common.closeBrowsers();
});
});
```

**Login.js:**

```
var Login = function() {

     this.login = async function(username, passwordKey){
     await browser.get('http://testwebsite.com/showCust');
     await element(by.name('USER')).sendKeys(username);
     await element(by.name('PASSWORD')).sendKeys(passwordKey);
     await element(by.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/input[9]')).click();
     await element(by.name('YES')).click();
     //browser.sleep(10000);

};
}
module.exports = new Login();
```

**CustomerSelection.js:**

```
var customer = function(){

    this.cusSelection = async function(){

     await element(by.css(['ng-model="selectedChannel.selected"']));
     await element(by.id('customer-auto-complete')).sendKeys('TestCustomer');
     //browser.sleep(500);

     await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]')).first().click();
    //browser.sleep(1500);
     await element(by.partialButtonText('Manage Customer')).click();
     browser.sleep(10000);      
    };
}
module.exports = new customer();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly says that promises rejection in `CustomerSelection.js` is not handled. As per stack trace, `await element(by.xpath(...))` is failing to resolve the promise.

The fix for this problem is to have a catch for `customer.cusSelection()` in `Scenario_01.js:` & handle the exception there.

By default the return type of every method with an `async` keyword is a promise. So you should either await on `customer.cusSelection()` in `Scenario_01.js:` or use a `then-catch` clause for assertion.

Something like this -

```
 it('CustomerSelection', async function() {
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
     let response = await customer.cusSelection();
 });

 // OR this to catch exceptions.

 it('CustomerSelection', function() {
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
     customer.cusSelection()
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
 });
```

Node.js is moving towards treating `unhandled promise rejections` similarly to `uncaughtException` errors in the future.

This means the upcoming node versions will terminate the process whenever it encounters a promise rejection ([reference](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0018_unhandled_promise_rejections)).

> Update - Code Snippet for **CustomerSelection.js**

```
var customer = function(){

    this.cusSelection = async function(){

    await element(by.css(['ng-model="selectedChannel.selected"']));
    await element(by.id('customer-auto-complete')).sendKeys('TestCustomer');
    //browser.sleep(500);

    // updating this snippet
    // await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]')).first().click();

    // to following
    let elements = await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]'));
    elements.first().click();

    //browser.sleep(1500);
    await element(by.partialButtonText('Manage Customer')).click();
    browser.sleep(10000);      
    };
}
module.exports = new customer();
```

Comment: Thanks Pal. Seems to be progressing now though ending up with "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible" error whilst trying to click on "await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]')).first().click();" element in CustomerSelection.js. Doesn't "await" wait for the element to be visible before looking for it ? Tried with 1500ms of sleep as well. It all works fine without Await/Async setup. Could you please suggest on what has to be done to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I am not that good at jasmine and protractor but can you catch the result of `await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]'))` in a variable and then use `variable.first().click()` to fire the click event? I am guessing `element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]'))` returns a promise here.

Comment: Tried to count and print the elements in array and I could see the value to be '1' which is expected, let autocompleteElem = await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]')).then(function(counter){console.log("No.Of Values:" +counter);});.But,ends up with Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined" if I try to click on the first element though."let autocompleteElem = await element.all(by.css('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]')).then(function(){autocompleteElem.first().click();});"  Any heads up ?

Comment: You should not be using await and then together. I will update my answer with the new code. Try using it and let me know if it works.

Comment: No luck mate. Ending up with below error.
TypeError: elements.first is not a function
    at customer.cusSelection (C:\Users\Ashish\Documents\Protractor\scripts\CustomerSelection.js:11:22)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)